# The Form hide and shows when using CreateParams

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I fix form suddenly hides and shows again

Here is what cause the issue

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            cp.Style &= ~0x02000000;  // Turn off WS_CLIPCHILDREN
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

I use this line of code so that form with background image loads faster and remove flickering issuer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
 {
     get
     {
        CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
        return myCp;
     }
 }
```

You cant hide, but can disable it by above code.

**Referance link:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms